# exclude a specific job in jenkins view filter

Tags: regex, jenkins

I have some jobs

```
        smoke_Page_Tests
        Page_1_Tests
        Page_2_Tests
```

I want to create a view in jenkins where 'Smoke' displays only smoke_Page_Tests
and "Page" displays all "Page_" tests but should not include Smoke tests. How to write a Regex for that

Comment: `^Page_` (String that starts with the given text) perhaps? No idea what regex jenkins supports.

Answer (score 2):

`^Page_`

This will match the beginning of those names.

`^Page_.*$`

This will match the whole name.

`^Page_\d+_Tests$`

This is a more precise regex, in case you prefer to play safer. This will match the whole name for anything from `Page_0_Tests` to `Page_9999_Tests` (and more). It won't match `Page_SomethingElse`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me be more precise. I have jobs like this too Page_admin_tests, Page_XXX12_tests, Page_yyy_tests. All these should go under Page tests except smoke tests. SO i am looking for something like (.*Page*.) & (!.*Smoke*.). But that does not work

Comment: The first two options should work, unless the regex is applied to the whole path, in which case of course it doesn't start with "Page". If that's the case, you can try with `(?<!smoke_)Page_` (negative lookbehind, but it doesn't work with JavaScript) or perhaps you can try with `\\Page_` (this would confirm Jenkins is analyzing the full path).

Answer (score 0):

you can use,this is :

Page_.*

tks